# Refresh Token approach to Fetch Calendar at any Time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need a help to make a decision related to integrating Microsoft Graph API to integrate office 365 Calendar, that can be accessed at any time. 
So for this, I am going to follow the approach to store the Refresh_Token so that whenever I need to access calendar of users I can generate token using this refresh token.

Is it the correct approach to access an user calendar at anytime?

Pls share your views here.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it the correct approach to access an user calendar at anytime?

Yes, you are right. And we should refresh the accesstoken using the refresh token before it is expired.

> Access tokens are short lived, and you must refresh them after they expire to continue accessing resources. You can do so by submitting another POST request to the /token endpoint, this time providing the refresh_token instead of the code.

For more detail, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token)